# Scala Play Framework templating complex objects

Tags: scala, playframework, play-templates

I am looking to render some templates and pass in nested objects. I havent seen many examples of this. It compiles, but Im looking more for ideas on how idiomatic the approach is.

For example, say the following case classes are built from a Slick database query

```scala
case class ThemedListOfAlbums(
 themeName: String,
 description: String,
 albums: List[Album]
)
case class Album(
 name: String,
 artist: String,
 imageUrl: String
 songs: List[Song]
)
case class Song(
 name: String,
 imageUrl: String,
 description: String
)
```

is it then just as simple as passing the complex object?:

```
@(user: User, catalogs: List[ThemedListOfAlbums])
 //stuff
<ul>
@for(c <- catalogs) {
 //?? want to render a partial for each catalog with a list of album images 
      //with song names on them
}
```

Is there a limit to levels of nesting before I need to rethink what I am trying to render completely?

a link to an example would be helpful if this qualifies as a "do your homework" question. cant seem to find any pertinent info

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to pass list of `ThemedListOfAlbums`, and use them however you need to show what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your Slick query properly populates `ThemedListOfAlbums.albums` and `Album.songs` then I don't see why this wouldn't work

I'd be more interested to see the kinds of queries you're using as this kind of approach can very quickly lead to a large amount of database queries for a single page

For example, one query could easily get a list of `Album` for the root object, but if each `Album` then makes a database call for a list of related `Songs` then you're going to have a huge amount of database requests, especially considering your view contains a list of `ThemedListOfAlbums`

Comment: Thats certainly a consideration, and one that almost lead me to think about a denormalized or nosql solution and just return the entire blob. However, the ThemedList is the result of a batch recommender system(user doesnt search) that gets populated in the db - each user will only have 5-10 possible ThemedLists at a given time. I could also create a materialized view

Comment: A view is definitely an option that could reduce the overall number of queries, but doing so would most likely return a lot of duplicate data. The only suggestion I can give, without understanding your solution in more detail, would be to possibly rethink your page structure to account for this. So, instead of bringing back all `song`s in each `album`, maybe just list each `album` on one page, with each linking to another page listing their `song`s.